# how to find dll for Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Messaging.Android?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

i am tyring to compile https://github.com/xamarinhq/app-evolve but getting lot of errors. when i checked reference Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Messaging.Android is shown missing can you please let me know how to resolve this.
Xamarin

Comment: ok i got it: its Install-Package Xam.Plugin.AzurePushNotification

Comment: Please add this as an answer too